Is there a way to prevent facet labels from being equal width (after rotation)
When I apply a facet_grid, sometimes the labels are quite wide, sometimes so wide that they don't fit, and I have to rotate them. This isn't a problem unless I want to facet by multiple different groups. In this case, it auto-sizes every single group's label to be the same as the longest label. A reproducible example should help clarify my meaning:
library(tidyverse)

data<-diamonds |> mutate(cut=paste("Super Duper Long Description Which Demonstrates The Issue",cut))

data |> filter(str_detect(cut,"(Ideal|Premium|Good)") & clarity%in%c("SI1","SI2","VS1","VS2")) |>
  ggplot(aes(x=color,y=price)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_grid(cut+clarity~.) +
  theme(strip.text.y = element_text(angle=0,vjust=0.5))


As you can see, the width of the longest label is applied to the "cut" strip as well.
In case it's not obvious, below is the desired output:

Is there a method to prevent this from happening? Or is this a bug that should be reported upstream?

One option to achieve your desired result would be to use ggh4x::facet_grid2 which using the strip= argument allows for strip text boxes of variable width or size:
library(tidyverse)
library(ggh4x)

data <- diamonds |>
  mutate(cut = paste("Super Duper Long Description Which Demonstrates The Issue", cut)) |>
  filter(
    str_detect(cut, "(Ideal|Premium|Good)") & clarity %in% c("SI1", "SI2", "VS1", "VS2")
  )


data |>
  ggplot(aes(x = color, y = price)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  ggh4x::facet_grid2(cut + clarity ~ .,
    strip = ggh4x::strip_vanilla(size = "variable")
  ) +
  theme(
    strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5)
  )



Additional note: although the original poster didn't use nested facets, the same method works with strip_nested instead of strip_vanilla and preserves the nesting aggregations!
